# How to resolve "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document when navigating to the previous page"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have icon on my page, which may occur multiple times on that page. I want to click on that icon, take a screenshot and then go back to previous page and click on other icon and perform the same operation: I am getting

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

when navigating to the previous page".
Below is my code:

```
List<WebElement> List = driver.findElements(Loc_AttachmentIcon);

for (WebElement e : List) {             
    if(e.getText().contains(".JPG")) {
        e.click();  
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
        driver.navigate().back();
    }

    else if(e.getText().contains(".jpg")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".png")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".PNG")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".gif")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".GIF")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else {
        e.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you hare me the locator of the icon or HTML of the icon link

Comment: The click on the element is causing the stale element exception. So @Guy answer is right. It might not be fast, but it it is the simplest solution

Comment: Rather than clicking the icon and following the link, why not just get the `href` from the link and verify that? Now your script runs a lot faster and the validation is basically the same (and you don't have to worry about stale element exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relocate the elements each iteration. You can use index to track your progress

```
int size = driver.findElements(Loc_AttachmentIcon).size();

for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(Loc_AttachmentIcon);
    WebElement e = list.get(i);

    if(e.getText().contains(".JPG")) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Element found in findelements refers and tied to the particular loaded page. If we navigate to another page or refresh the same page. The references stored for the elements becomes invalid. Those elements were dead due to reload of page. So you end up in StaleElementException.
Please read [this](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) more detail about StaleElement.

In this type of case, we have to iterate with locators instead of elements as page navigation happens.

I assume that your icon have following html DOM and use xpath to locate it.

```
<a href="link to the icon.png" > Some Icon <a>
```

Your code can be rewritten as,

```java
int iconCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[href]")).size();
for (int i = 1; i < iconCount; i++) {
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[href])["+i+"]"));
    if(e.getText().contains(".JPG")) {
        e.click();
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".jpg")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".png")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".PNG")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".gif")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
    else if(e.getText().contains(".GIF")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Jpg file");
    }
}
```